# Adding JS code Always showing below footer

Tags: magento-1.8, javascript

I am inserting JotForm JS code in specific CMS Page but it always showing after footer. Even when I add jQuery CDN, it always showing after footer. I have tried `head.phtml`, `header.phtml`, `CMS page editor` and `CMS page XML` section but it still showing after footer.

> ```
> 1- [JotForm] <script type="text/javascript" src="https://form.jotform.com/jsform/90594783337166"></script>
> ```
>
> 2-
>   [tech_support_inquiry](https://tonerrefillkits.com/tech_support_inquiry)

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to simply add js in CMS page:

> Admin> SMS > pages > Design > Layout update XML >

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addLinkRel">
        <rel>text/javascript</rel>
        <href>https://your/js/url.js</href>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: still showing in below footer.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? My jotform forms are all showing up below the footer unless I use iframe